# Domain controller is not listening on port 445

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, port, domain-controller, sysvol

Is there a way to find why the DC is not listening on 445?

-> Firewall rules checked , no denies found and the traffic is allowed.
-> file share and print share services running.

What else to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be very odd for a Domain Controller or, frankly, any Windows Server machine in general, to not be listening on TCP port 445.

The "Server" service handles listening on TCP port 445. You should see the "System" process ID reflected as the PID assigned to the listening socket on TCP port 445 in a `netstat -a -o`.

Verify the "Server" service is started. If it isn't, start it. It is necessary for a DC to function properly. Without it clients would not be able to apply Group Policy (among other problems, I'm sure).

Comment: "Server" Service is running fine, and netstat -a -o doesnt show 445 anywhere.

Comment: Wow. You have really, really oddball scenario there. Is it listening on TCP port 139? What does `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters` look like?

Comment: Its listening on 139 ; i compared the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters" settings to a working DC which is listening on 445 and they both are exactly same.

Comment: I'm at a bit of a loss. That this point I'd probably do a logged boot with Process Monitor and start grubbing through the tons of logs it will generate. That's utterly bizarre.